# Is it possible to create multiple references to a file on Macintosh?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

What I mean is that I want the same file to exist in 2 different locations, so that when I save it in 1 location it updates in the other location. I'm running OSX Yosemite, btw. Is this possible?

Comment: Unless you're talking about _writing software_ this question belongs on [apple.se]. And the answer to your question is probably a [symlink.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)

Comment: Or the answer could be a hard link, if it's on the same volume.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to have the file on the same computer, a symlink will do the trick:

- Fire up terminal
- Navigate to the directory you want to have the symlink in *cd /path/to/your/file*
- do *ln -s /any/file/on/the/disk linked-file* where "*linked-file*" will be the name of the file you want

If you're looking to have the file on a separate computer or on a network drive, you should probably look into rsync.